# Suggestions for an offline CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, markup, offlineapps

I am looking for a way to create a blog (with some other informative pages) using offline CMS.

What I mean by "offline CMS" is:

- I should be able to write using a markup which is abstract (not HTML, or XML). Something like the `MarkDown` or `Textile` systems.
- The entries will be edited offline on my PC
- When I am done, I will need to (re)generate the final HTML output and rsync it to my server.
- For page comments, I can use something like the `Disqus` service.
- In effect, the final site will be static.

Nice to have feature: Support for categories, tags, and other such navigational aids.

Is there anything like this out there?

Edit: Opensource/Free, cross-platform tools preferable.

**Edit #2** Thanks to Adam, I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186290/best-static-website-generator) on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be a static site generator.  There is [Jekyll](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/) written in ruby which supports both Textile, and Markdown.  Its old homepage used Disqus.  It seems to fit your needs. There is also the django-based [Hyde](http://ringce.com/blog/2009/introducing_hyde).

Comment: Thanks for the keywords "static site generator". Using those I found another similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186290/best-static-website-generator

Answer (score 1):

I also searched for something like this. I found some offline Wikis e.q. [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com), but this is not want I wanted, same for you I think. There's [CityDesk](http://www.fogcreek.com/citydesk) from FogCreek, pretty good, "old", avout 300 $ (to expensive I think).

I now use [Incomedia Website X5](http://www.websitex5.com) which is not a CMS but easy to use anyway.

Edit: Oh, I forgot this one, might be what you want (Java, free): [www.thingamablog.com](http://www.thingamablog.com)

Comment: Yeah, I use TiddlyWiki, but it's not suitable here. Thanks for the other links. CityDesk seems to be Windows only (They have a free starter edition, btw). So is Ocomedia Website X5 :(

Comment: @HRJ: The starter edition is really limited. If you use it for some time, you will have to buy the full version.

Comment: Last I heard, CityDesk was under-maintained, and not too profitable, and now no one seems to use it except Joel on Software. And like you said, it is proprietary, costly, and Windows-only.

Answer (score 1):

I have written [an offline CMS of my own called Latemp](http://web-cpan.shlomifish.org/latemp/) based on [Website Meta Language](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/projects/website-meta-language/) (which I did not write, but now maintain), some CPAN modules, and other programs. It is not too fast, but it is powerful and flexible, and I find it much more transparent than Jekyll, and as opposed to Jekyll, it supports incremental build based on timestamps (using GNU make).

There is some support in Website Meta Language for writing in the so-called “lightweight markup languages” (Perl POD specifically), and Latemp should support it as well, but I personally don't like them much, and prefer having a full control of the XHTML (or alternatively using an XML format such as [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) or [XML-Grammar-Fiction](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/projects/XML-Grammar/Fiction/)). I do have some pages written in or using AsciiDoc and other lightweight markup languages on my site.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles across this. I think a flat-file cms would do the trick. Flat-file means it runs off files, not a database.
Try grav. I know it interprets markdown from basic text files.
https://getgrav.org/

Comment: This is a very old question that has (so far) escaped being closed. Questions asking for software recommendations are not permitted on Stack Overflow, because they attract answers that tend to look a lot like spam. If you're in any way affiliated with "Grav", you should disclose your affiliation. Otherwise, ignore the downvotes, they appear to be from users who suspected your post was spam.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info. Had no idea!
I've actually never tried Grav - just happened to be doing similar research myself and remembered it.